# Consulta array en AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

estoy intentando obtener mediante ajax y la  llamada a un método en php un array de todas las cookies que tengo declaradas, para luego obtener el valor en una vista determinada y aplicar jquery y ajuste del diseño. Las cookies son ajustes visuales que el usuario define para personalizar su aplicación.

La llamada AJAX, la realizo de la siguiente forma.

```
    $js = <<<EOT

$( function() {
   obtenerCookie();
});

    function obtenerCookie(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '$url',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $(".feed").css('background-color', data);
            }
        });


        }


EOT;
if (isset($_COOKIE['colorPanel'])) {

    $this->registerJs($js);
}
```

y el método obtener las cookies es el siguiente:

```
 public function actionObtenercookie()
    {
        $cookies = Yii::$app->request->cookies;
        return $cookies;
    }
```

La idea es poder obtener el dato de cada cookie en ajax, con algo parecido a data['BackgroundColor'], y no tener que establecer un método para cada cookie de datos definida por el usuario.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Y qué problema o error tienes en concreto?

Comment: Necesito leer el array $cookies en la consulta ajax.

Comment: Eso lo entendemos, pero qué obtienes ahora de ese procedimiento? La idea es poder responder sin tener que armarmos un banco de pruebas

Comment: De entrada tu escenario es muy raro. ¿Tienes la petición Ajax en el mismo archivo que devuelve el array `$cookeis`? Es que veo en el Ajax una variable `$url` que no sé que hace ahí ¿? Ajax debe estar en un archivo distinto al que procesa los datos en el servidor. Dinos cómo tienes organizado tu escenario porque ni siquiera eso se entiende. Por ejemplo: *tengo el Ajax en tal archivo y hago la petición a tal archivo del servidor*